# Re-allocate released objects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, ios5

I'm wondering if this can be done: I'm using a library for Panorama that uses a lot of memory, and there is no memory management in the library. It uses HTML5 and JavaScript to load Panorama images. However, when I call this library, it gives me a memory warning `Received memory warning.`. When this happens,`dealloc` is called, and releases many things that I have in the view. So, I want to re-allocate all released objects again once I've done with the library. Is there is a solution that I can use to handle this issue? Sometimes the app crashes.

Note: the library is KRPano, it's amazing but the memory issue is not handled yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects are released it's because you do not own them. 
Try to call `retain` on each object you want to control and it should not get automatically released.

Comment: Actually i own all the object that released, but the system autorelease the object by it self, i've never call release on any object.